# Why is this camping light deadly?

Tags: capacitor, ac, mains, capacitive, full-bridge

I am learning, so go easy on me, if you can.

In a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwqFkelUs_g) with BigClive, he takes apart a camping light and says it's deadly when you have mains plugged in and usb plugged in at the same time. In that situation the USB can be live. [image: circuit]

Here's a picture of the circuit he draws in the video.

I am assuming it is deadly because it uses a capacitive dropper and if the plug is inserted backwards it doesn't drop the voltage and the USB is sitting at 240v?

Or is there another reason?

Comment: Exactly--it's deadly because it provides a straight connection between externally-accessible parts and 240V mains.

Comment: The video is totally worth it for the "gay Dalek" comment alone!

Comment: Is it only deadly when plugged in incorrectly?

Comment: It's also deadly because in the event of a fault on neutral, it could send that current to ground through the USB. I wonder what a USB cable would look like with more than ~30V going through it.

Comment: @JonRB Except for the straight path to death through the diode bridge...

Comment: This is why we have ETL's

Comment: Considering you won't go camping with your tower and a laptop or mobile uses an isolated supply, you are likely to experience a shock from wet socks or shoes to earth from either the laptop leakage filter current or a possibly lethal *exciting* current if the L-N is reversed in a wet tent with damp clothes or skin exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most outlets aren't polarized.  Even in places where the outlets are polarized, mistakes happen.

There's a straight connection between the outlet and the ground of the USB port.  All there is in between the two is a diode.

If that wire is connected to neutral in the outlet, then nothing bad will happen if you touch the USB ground.

If you plug it in the other way around (or the polarized outlet is wired backwards,)  then you have the full line voltage on the USB ground.

That can be deadly.

Additionally, even if it is connected the right way around, all that's between you and line voltage is a capacitor.

If it is a Y rated capacitor and it fails, then you are safe - Y rated capacitors are **supposed** to fail open.  They almost always fail open, but do you want to bet your life that a company that builds a capacitive dropper powersupply with user accesible connections will also think to use a Y rated capacitor?

Even if it doesn't kill you, it can destroy any laptop or other USB source you connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

The impedance of that capacitor at 50Hz is about 3200 Ohms. Which means a current of 75mA if I have done the maths correctly. The problem is that the voltage at the user end will rise until it either gets to 240VAC or it drives that 75mA through whatever - including you. Which is quite possibly fatal. There is nothing to "tap off" that current to keep the voltage within sane limits as far as I can see. Normally there would be something like a zener to do that. They seem to be relying on the LEDs

Answer (score 0):

> Is it only deadly when plugged in incorrectly?

Neither the mains plug nor the inlet connector appear to be polarised, there appears to be no indication of which way around is correct is no indication given of which way round is "correct".

> I am assuming it is deadly because it uses a capacitive dropper and if the plug is inserted backwards it doesn't drop the voltage and the USB is sitting at 240v?

If the plugs are inserted such that the live connection goes to the rectifier and the neutral to the capacitor then everything connected to the output of the rectifier will be live.

If the plugs are inserted such that the neutral connection goes to the rectifier and the live to the capacitor then you don't have the immediate danger, but you still have a product that would not pass safety standards. If the neutral were to break, the components that absorb the current were to fail open-circuit or the dropper capacitor were to fail short then you are back to having a live output.